# Having two columns in a single unordered list

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

You have to press "Full Page" to see the attached snippet display.

I'd like to line up my options so that they are in alignment, with the checkmark being a little to the left.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap/latest/css/bootstrap.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
   <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
     <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Showing: C
      <span class="caret"></span>
      </a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
       <li><a href="##">A</a></li>
       <li><a href="##">B</a></li>
       <li><a href="##">&#10003; C</a></li>
       <li><a href="##">D</a></li>
       <li><a href="##">E</a></li>
      </ul>
     </li>
             </ul>
         </div>

<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap/latest/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example using font awesome (or glyphicons).

```css
.checked {
  position: relative;
}
.checked:before {
  content: "\f00c";
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding-right: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="dropdown"> <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Showing: C
      <span class="caret"></span>
      </a>

      <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
        <li><a href="##">A</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="##">B</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="checked"></i> C</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="##">D</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="##">E</a>

        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Or in UTF-16 Hex

```
.checked {
    position: relative;
}
.checked:before {
    content:"\2713";
    font-size: 14px;
    padding-right: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    right: 5px;
}
```

Comment: This works. But I think I'll keep the question open for possible solutions without loading font-awesome. One of the reasons I like unicode is because it's (potentially) so light weight.

Comment: I actually added a UNICODE answer yesterday. See above.